# Cannot Access Local Network Shares (Strange Schannel and lsass.exe issues)

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, domain, lsass

When I browse to my own computer's shares by going to \\MYCOMPUTERNAME\ ; I cannot access any of the shares on my LOCAL machine (nor can I access them remotely) and it generates about 40 of the following errors in my system event log:

> The following fatal alert was
>   generated: 10. The internal error
>   state is 1203.

Details:

```
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
  <Provider Name="Schannel" Guid="{1F678132-5938-4686-9FDC-C8FF68F15C85}" /> 
  <EventID>36888</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-04-05T13:52:09.144278900Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>79628</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="552" ThreadID="672" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DEVELOP4.CONTOSO.COM</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
  <Data Name="AlertDesc">10</Data> 
  <Data Name="ErrorState">1203</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Additonal information:

- The process that is generating the error is lsass.exe
- OS: Windows7 Professional x64
- Joined to Domain: Yes
- I was able to access the shares locally in the past
- I am having the same issue on 3 other computers that have similar configurations

Any help would be greatly appreciated, because I have no idea what's wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue. I had port 444 and 445 bound to SSL on a local development website in IIS which was apparently conflicting with *something* (I'm not sure what it was conflicting with) After removing those bindings (SSL to 444/445) in IIS I was able to access my local shares without any issues.

Comment: Indeed, 445 is used by the LAN manager (SMB/CIFS) over TCP/IP, i.e. anything about network shares, pipes, mailslots ... it is a needed port. You mustn't tinker with it. Linux machines with `smbd` will usually also use that port.